# highcharts gauge use with negative values

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I want to create a gauge chart like this.

[image]

So i have tried highchart library. I could draw the chart with positive values.

like this.

```
$(function () {

var rate_data = {
    "ranges":[
        {"name":"Maintain","start":0, "end":0.12147311428571},        
        {"name":"Slow", "start":0.12147311428571, "end":0.21491397142857},          
        {"name":"Adequate", "start":0.21491397142857, "end":0.8503118}, 
        {"name":"Too Fast",  "start":0.8503118, "end":1.4109569429}
], 
"value":0.4177
};

   $('#container').highcharts({

    chart: {
        type: 'gauge',
        plotBackgroundColor: null,
        plotBackgroundImage: null,
        plotBorderWidth: 0,
        plotShadow: false
    },        
    title: {
        text: 'Weight Oscillation Rate'
    },
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },
    pane: {
        startAngle: -150,
        endAngle: 150,
        background: [{
            backgroundColor: {
                linearGradient: { x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1 },
                stops: [
                    [0, '#FFF'],
                    [1, '#333']
                ]
            },
            borderWidth: 0,
            outerRadius: '109%'
        }, {
            backgroundColor: {
                linearGradient: { x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1 },
                stops: [
                    [0, '#333'],
                    [1, '#FFF']
                ]
            },
            borderWidth: 1,
            outerRadius: '107%'
        }, {
            // default background
        }, {
            backgroundColor: '#DDD',
            borderWidth: 0,
            outerRadius: '105%',
            innerRadius: '103%'
        }]
    },

    // the value axis
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        max: 1.4109569429,

        minorTickInterval: 'auto',
        minorTickWidth: 1,
        minorTickLength: 10,
        minorTickPosition: 'inside',
        minorTickColor: '#666',

        tickPixelInterval: 30,
        tickWidth: 2,
        tickPosition: 'side',
        tickLength: 10,
        tickColor: '#666',
        labels: {
            step: 2,
            rotation: 'auto'
        },
        title: {
            text: ''
        },
        plotBands: [{
            from: rate_data['ranges'][0]['start'],
            to: rate_data['ranges'][0]['end'],
            color: '#FF8000' // orange
        }, {
            from: rate_data['ranges'][1]['start'],
            to: rate_data['ranges'][1]['end'],
            color: '#DDDF0D' // yellow
        }, {
            from: rate_data['ranges'][2]['start'],
            to: rate_data['ranges'][2]['end'],
            color: '#01DF01' // green
        }, {
            from: rate_data['ranges'][3]['start'],
            to: rate_data['ranges'][3]['end'],
            color: '#DF5353' // red
        }]        
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Speed',
        data: [80],            
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: ' '
        }
    }]

}, 

// Add some life
function (chart) {
    if (!chart.renderer.forExport) {

        var point = chart.series[0].points[0],
            newVal,
            inc = Math.round((Math.random() - 0.5) * 20);

        point.update(rate_data['value']);  

    }
});
});
```

But it is upset with negative values. This is my new array.

```
var rate_data = {
    "ranges":[
        {"name":"Maintain","start":0, "end":-0.12147311428571},        
        {"name":"Slow", "start":-0.12147311428571, "end":-0.21491397142857},          
        {"name":"Adequate", "start":-0.21491397142857, "end":-0.8503118}, 
        {"name":"Too Fast",  "start":-0.8503118, "end":-1.4109569429}
], 
"value":-0.4177
};
```

Please check http://jsfiddle.net/fWvCT/

I couldn't find the solution in the Internet. (Also i need add the names in the array as label. Is it possible? )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of problems here.

1) you have your yAxis min set to 0.  It won't display negative numbers this way.  Adjust your min and max to reflect the actual values needed.

2) having done that, you'll see that your bands are all out of whack.

You have the start/end values specified in reverse: the start should be the lower number, and the end the higher.

`Example`:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/YNwvn/

Answer (score 0):

For someone looking to get the same look and feel, [this](https://jsfiddle.net/Johnbosco/4heup0n8/) will help

see script below

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {

    chart: {
        type: 'gauge',
        backgroundColor: 'transparent'
    },

    title: {
        text: ''
    },

    pane: {
        background:null,
        startAngle: -90,
        endAngle: 90,
        center: ['50%', '50%'],
     },

    // the value axis
    yAxis: {
                lineWidth: 0,
        min: -1.4,
        max: 0,
        minorTickInterval: 'auto',
        minorTickWidth: 1,
        minorTickLength: 10,
        minorTickPosition: 'inside',
        minorTickColor: '#666',

        tickPixelInterval: 0.1,
        tickWidth: 2,
        tickPosition: 'side',
        tickLength: 10,
        tickColor: '#666',
        labels: {
            step: 2,
            y:20,
            style:{
              color:'#000',
              cursor:'default',
              fontSize:'14px'
            }
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Progress',
            style: {
              color: '#FFF',
              fontWeight: 'bold'
            },
            y:60
        },
        plotBands: [{
            from: -1.40,
            to: -0.85,
            color: '#3285167d', // green
                thickness:50,
            label:{
                text:'Too fast!',
              textAlign: 'center',
              x: 160
            }
        }, {
            from: -0.85,
            to: -0.21,
            color: '#DDDF0D', // yellow
            thickness:50
        }, {
            from: -0.21,
            to: -0.12,
            color: '#DF5353', // red
            thickness:50
        }, {
            from: -0.12,
            to: 0,
            color: 'blue', // blue
            thickness:50
        }]
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Progress',
        data: [-0.1],
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: ' Progress'
        }
    }]

},
// Add some life
function (chart) {
    
});
```

```css
#container {
    height: 400px; 
}

.highcharts-figure, .highcharts-data-table table {
    min-width: 310px; 
    max-width: 500px;
    margin: 1em auto;
}

.highcharts-data-table table {
    font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 1px solid #EBEBEB;
    margin: 10px auto;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 500px;
}
.highcharts-data-table caption {
    padding: 1em 0;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    color: #555;
}
.highcharts-data-table th {
    font-weight: 600;
    padding: 0.5em;
}
.highcharts-data-table td, .highcharts-data-table th, .highcharts-data-table caption {
    padding: 0.5em;
}
.highcharts-data-table thead tr, .highcharts-data-table tr:nth-child(even) {
    background: #f8f8f8;
}
.highcharts-data-table tr:hover {
    background: #f1f7ff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>

<figure class="highcharts-figure">
    <div id="container"></div>
</figure>
```